# Simple widget JavaScript library

Tags: javascript, widget

I've been asked to write a web application in PHP to handle customers, sales, estimates, invoices... I think I could benefit from a JavaScript library that could encapsulate some basic UI functionality (sortable listings, masked input fields, date pickers...) but I don't want to adopt a heavy framework that forces me to go through a steep learning curve and design my whole app around its API. I just want an unobtrusive enhancement.

jQuery is my library of choice for regular JavaScript tasks but I find that [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) lacks important widgets/features and it's hard to style.

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sortable lists, masked input fields and date pickers can all be added to your existing jQuery setup without having to rely on jQueryUI in the form of jQuery plugins.

(add http:// before each url)

- datepicker - plugins.jquery.com/project/datepick
- draggable sortable lists - plugins.jquery.com/project/listsort
- numerous validation/form plugins - plugins.jquery.com/taxonomy/term/68

Comment: I guess I'll try this approach. I can also leverage my jQuery knowledge to write reusable code. I'm too old to learn a new framework ;-)